# how to make this htaccess for subfolder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Can someone help me fix `.htaccess` to work for subfolder app installation?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /tube
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
</ifModule>
```

http://yoobro.bro/tube/login&return=moderator - 404 error

I can see index once I RewriteBase /tube but nothing else seems to work. All gives me a "404 not found" error.

This `.htaccess` is in subdirectory, main site has `.htaccess` to, its wordpress site that is main and wordpress `.htaccess` is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the slash before index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /tube/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: It does work. I tested it in a subfolder with a WordPress site in the root folder. Make sure you have the htacess and the index.php file inside the /tube/ folder. And delete cache, this kind of things get strongly cached some times.